# H2 jar compile to native windows code

Tags: java, exe, h2

does anyone has experience with compiling H2 jar into windows native code using e.g. Excelsior JET. Is there a chance that it could work ? Asking that, because I am considering to convert my whole java app to native EXE.

Thanks,
Lubos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, H2 doesn't make use of any native code.
It does however, perform some reflection, so some degree of hand tweaking of Excelsior is likely to be required.